# How to sort alphanumeric columns in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
d = {'cell':['cell_D1_TX_L_90','cell_D11_TX_L_90','cell_D14_TX_L_90','cell_D4_TX_L_90','cell_D3_TX_L_90','cell1_D23_TX_L_90','cell1_D2_TX_L_90','cell1_D4_TX_L_90','cell1_D11_TX_L_90','cell1_D1P5_TX_L_90','cell_D1_TY_L_90','cell_D11_TY_L_90','cell_D14_TY_L_90','cell_D4_TY_L_90','cell_D3_TY_L_90'],'D1':[5, 2, 2, 6,6,5, 2, 2, 6,6,5, 2, 2, 6,6]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
print(df)

        cell            D1
0      cell_D1_TX_L_90   5
1     cell_D11_TX_L_90   2
2     cell_D14_TX_L_90   2
3      cell_D4_TX_L_90   6
4      cell_D3_TX_L_90   6
5    cell1_D23_TX_L_90   5
6     cell1_D2_TX_L_90   2
7     cell1_D4_TX_L_90   2
8    cell1_D11_TX_L_90   6
9   cell1_D1P5_TX_L_90   6
10     cell_D1_TY_L_90   5
11    cell_D11_TY_L_90   2
12    cell_D14_TY_L_90   2
13     cell_D4_TY_L_90   6
```

i want to do alpha numeric sorting to the cell column,

there are five fields

EG:
**cell1_D11_TX_L_90**
1st field --> cell1

2nd field --> D11

3rd field --> TX

4th field --> L

5th field --> 90

1st field and 3rd field can be different that can change in the dataframe
like

cell_D11_TX_L_90 & cell_D11_TY_L90  -->  3rd field --> TX and TY

cell_D11_TX_L_90 & cell1_D11_TX_L90 --> 1st field --> cell and cell1

i want to sort the cell column alpha numerically by taking second field in to account with unique set of 1st field and 3rd field.

if i do normal sorting to the 'cell' column

```
    cell  D1
8    cell1_D11_TX_L_90   6
9   cell1_D1P5_TX_L_90   6
5    cell1_D23_TX_L_90   5
6     cell1_D2_TX_L_90   2
7     cell1_D4_TX_L_90   2
1     cell_D11_TX_L_90   2
11    cell_D11_TY_L_90   2
2     cell_D14_TX_L_90   2
12    cell_D14_TY_L_90   2
0      cell_D1_TX_L_90   5
10     cell_D1_TY_L_90   5
4      cell_D3_TX_L_90   6
14     cell_D3_TY_L_90   6
3      cell_D4_TX_L_90   6
13     cell_D4_TY_L_90   6
```

**Expected output:**

```
        cell            D1
0      cell_D1_TX_L_90   5
1      cell_D3_TX_L_90   6
2      cell_D4_TX_L_90   6
3     cell_D11_TX_L_90   2
4     cell_D14_TX_L_90   2
5   cell1_D1P5_TX_L_90   6
6     cell1_D2_TX_L_90   2
7     cell1_D4_TX_L_90   2
8    cell1_D11_TX_L_90   6
9    cell1_D23_TX_L_90   5
10     cell_D1_TY_L_90   5
11     cell_D3_TY_L_90   6
12     cell_D4_TY_L_90   6
13    cell_D11_TY_L_90   2
14    cell_D14_TY_L_90   2
```

i implemented the below code but it is slow since my dataframe size is in 300k-500k rows.

```
df_split=df.assign(list_col=lambda df:df['cell'].str.split('_',3,expand=False),function=lambda df:df.list_col.str[0],drive=lambda df:df.list_col.str[1],type=lambda df:df.list_col.str[2],length=lambda df:df.list_col.str[3])
print(df_split)
df_split['function'] = df_split['function']+'_'+df_split['type']
df_split.drop(columns=['list_col','length','type'],inplace=True)
df_final=pd.DataFrame()
for function in list(df_split['function'].unique()):
        df_split.loc[df_split['function']==function,'drive']=df_split['drive'].str.replace('D','',regex=True)
        df_split.loc[df_split['function']==function,'drive']=df_split['drive'].str.replace('P','.',regex=True)
        df_inter=df_split.loc[df_split['function']==function]
        df_inter.loc[:,'drive']=pd.to_numeric(df_inter['drive'])
        df_inter=df_inter.sort_values(by=['drive'],ascending=True)
        print(df_inter)
        df_final=pd.concat([df_final,df_inter])

        cell            D1
0      cell_D1_TX_L_90   5
1      cell_D3_TX_L_90   6
2      cell_D4_TX_L_90   6
3     cell_D11_TX_L_90   2
4     cell_D14_TX_L_90   2
5   cell1_D1P5_TX_L_90   6
6     cell1_D2_TX_L_90   2
7     cell1_D4_TX_L_90   2
8    cell1_D11_TX_L_90   6
9    cell1_D23_TX_L_90   5
10     cell_D1_TY_L_90   5
11     cell_D3_TY_L_90   6
12     cell_D4_TY_L_90   6
13    cell_D11_TY_L_90   2
14    cell_D14_TY_L_90   2
```

Please let me know any efficient solution to this with less runtime?

natsort is an easy way but unfortunately it is not available in my workspace.

Comment: It's not clear what the sort order is meant to be to get from your input to your expected output. Can you describe the sort more explicitly?

Comment: i updated the description, please check now

Comment: You can perhaps try splitting the column 'cell' into 5 columns `df[['field_1', 'field_2', 'field_3', 'field_4', field_5]] = df['cell'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(str(x).split("_")))`. Then you can try using `df.sort_values(by=['field_1', 'field_3', 'field_2'])`.

Comment: field_2 is not sorted properly by doing so

Comment: What specifically is wrong with how `field_2` is sorted using the above method? Is it reversed or is there another criterion missing from the description?

Comment: when i run the code, it is not getting sorted as expected (field_2)

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```py
def key_func(series):
    x = series.str.extract(r'^([^_]+)_D(\d+)(?:P(\d+))?_([^_]+)')
    x[[1,2]] = x[[1,2]].astype(float)
    return x[[3, 0, 1, 2]].agg(tuple, axis=1)

print(df.sort_values(by='cell', key=key_func))
```

Prints:

```
                  cell  D1
0      cell_D1_TX_L_90   5
4      cell_D3_TX_L_90   6
3      cell_D4_TX_L_90   6
1     cell_D11_TX_L_90   2
2     cell_D14_TX_L_90   2
9   cell1_D1P5_TX_L_90   6
6     cell1_D2_TX_L_90   2
7     cell1_D4_TX_L_90   2
8    cell1_D11_TX_L_90   6
5    cell1_D23_TX_L_90   5
10     cell_D1_TY_L_90   5
14     cell_D3_TY_L_90   6
13     cell_D4_TY_L_90   6
11    cell_D11_TY_L_90   2
12    cell_D14_TY_L_90   2
```

---

EDIT: With updated data:

```py
d = {'cell':['cell_D1P5_TX_L_90','cell_D1P4_TX_L_90','cell_D14_TX_L_90','cell_D4_TX_L_90','cell_D3_TX_L_90','cell1_D23_TX_L_90','cell1_D2_TX_L_90','cell1_D4_TX_L_90','cell1_D11_TX_L_90','cell1_D1P5_TX_L_90','cell_D1_TY_L_90','cell_D11_TY_L_90','cell_D14_TY_L_90','cell_D4_TY_L_90','cell_D3_TY_L_90'],'D1':[5, 2, 2, 6,6,5, 2, 2, 6,6,5, 2, 2, 6,6]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

def key_func(series):
    x = series.str.extract(r'^([^_]+)_D(\d+)(?:P(\d+))?_([^_]+)')
    x[[1,2]] = x[[1,2]].astype(float)
    return x[[3, 0, 1, 2]].agg(tuple, axis=1)

print(df.sort_values(by='cell', key=key_func))
```

Prints:

```
                  cell  D1
1    cell_D1P4_TX_L_90   2
0    cell_D1P5_TX_L_90   5
4      cell_D3_TX_L_90   6
3      cell_D4_TX_L_90   6
2     cell_D14_TX_L_90   2
9   cell1_D1P5_TX_L_90   6
6     cell1_D2_TX_L_90   2
7     cell1_D4_TX_L_90   2
8    cell1_D11_TX_L_90   6
5    cell1_D23_TX_L_90   5
10     cell_D1_TY_L_90   5
14     cell_D3_TY_L_90   6
13     cell_D4_TY_L_90   6
11    cell_D11_TY_L_90   2
12    cell_D14_TY_L_90   2
```

---

EDIT 2: Using `np.lexsort`:

```py
x = df['cell'].str.extract(r'^([^_]+)_D(\d+)(?:P(\d+))?_([^_]+)')
df = df.iloc[np.lexsort((x[2].astype(float), x[1].astype(float), x[0], x[3]))]
print(df)
```

Comment: Instead of aggregation as tuple you can also return the output of `np.lexsort` this should be more efficient. Or sort the crafted dataframe and use its index to reindex (without`sort_values`) ;)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! --> when i have D1P4 and D1P5 in the 2nd field --> algorithm is not sorting properly --> D1P4 should come first than D1P5 -->:dataframe used for testing-->
d = {'cell':['cell_D1P5_TX_L_90','cell_D1P4_TX_L_90','cell_D14_TX_L_90','cell_D4_TX_L_90','cell_D3_TX_L_90','cell1_D23_TX_L_90','cell1_D2_TX_L_90','cell1_D4_TX_L_90','cell1_D11_TX_L_90','cell1_D1P5_TX_L_90','cell_D1_TY_L_90','cell_D11_TY_L_90','cell_D14_TY_L_90','cell_D4_TY_L_90','cell_D3_TY_L_90'],'D1':[5, 2, 2, 6,6,5, 2, 2, 6,6,5, 2, 2, 6,6]}

Comment: @sandeep or would be much easier to use `natsort`. You can install it as user in your environment.

Comment: @sandeep When I use your data I get correctly first `D1P4` and then `D1P5` (see my edit.)

Comment: @mozway natsort will be better option, i requested them to install it

Comment: @mozway I've added a solution with `np.lexsort`. Do you mean it should be used like this?

Comment: Yes, looks good @Andrej ;) (your already have my +1)

Answer (score 1):

I tried to replicate your code in a cleaner way (I guess) and I think using the `sort_values` is better than using loops and joins.

I also tried to make it as close as possible to your code, so if you have any questions reply them.

```py
import pandas as pd

d = {'cell':['cell_D1_TX_L_90','cell_D11_TX_L_90','cell_D14_TX_L_90','cell_D4_TX_L_90','cell_D3_TX_L_90','cell1_D23_TX_L_90','cell1_D2_TX_L_90','cell1_D4_TX_L_90','cell1_D11_TX_L_90','cell1_D1P5_TX_L_90','cell_D1_TY_L_90','cell_D11_TY_L_90','cell_D14_TY_L_90','cell_D4_TY_L_90','cell_D3_TY_L_90'],'D1':[5, 2, 2, 6,6,5, 2, 2, 6,6,5, 2, 2, 6,6]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

def sort_func(series_in):
    # create a small dataframe
    ss = (
        series_in
        .str.split('_', 3, expand=True)
        .rename(columns={0:'function', 1:'drive', 2:'type', 3:'length'})
    )

    # convert the drive to numeric
    ss['drive'] = pd.to_numeric(
        ss['drive']
            .replace('D', '', regex=True)
            .replace('P', '.', regex=True)
    )

    # sort
    ss.sort_values(['type', 'function', 'drive', 'length'], inplace=True)

    # return the index
    return ss.index

# apply the sort function
df.sort_values('cell', key=sort_func, inplace=True, ignore_index=True)

# show result
print(df)
```

output

```
                  cell  D1
0      cell_D1_TX_L_90   5
1      cell_D4_TX_L_90   6
2      cell_D3_TX_L_90   6
3     cell_D14_TX_L_90   2
4     cell_D11_TX_L_90   2
5   cell1_D1P5_TX_L_90   6
6     cell1_D2_TX_L_90   2
7     cell1_D4_TX_L_90   2
8    cell1_D11_TX_L_90   6
9    cell1_D23_TX_L_90   5
10     cell_D1_TY_L_90   5
11     cell_D4_TY_L_90   6
12     cell_D3_TY_L_90   6
13    cell_D14_TY_L_90   2
14    cell_D11_TY_L_90   2
```